# MKAnnotation looses title and subtitle when given a custom icon

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Ok so I am making an iOS application using the MapKit framework. I have got the functionality working but am now having trouble when changing the icon of the annotation. I can change the annotations icon but when I do so the annotation looses it's title and subtitle values (nothing pops up when tapped). I think maybe the issue is due to something like not giving the annotation an identifier when first made but I am not sure...

If anyone could let me know whats going on it would be greatly appreciated!

The code to add annotation is:

```
-(void)addAnnotationAtLattitude:(double)lattitude withLongitude:(double)longitude withTitle:(NSString *)title withSubtitle:(NSString *)subtitle{
//Handles the adding off the anotation
CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
annotationCoord.latitude = lattitude;
annotationCoord.longitude = longitude;

MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
annotationPoint.title = title;
annotationPoint.subtitle = subtitle;
[self.MessageMap addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
```

}

and the code to change the icon (via delegate method ) is:

```
    -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView viewForAnnotation:(id 
<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation     
reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
    }

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomMapAnnotationIcon"];//mycustom image
annotationView.annotation = annotation;

return annotationView;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are `annotationView.enabled` and `annotationView.canShowCallout` set to `YES`?

Comment: you are correct. I thought I already tried this but apparently not! Many thanks.